Не рендерится элемент с эксклюзивным url
У меня проблема с url. Я хочу открывать элемент с дополнительной эксклюзивной адресной строкой.
NavLink элемент:

 let addressBar = "/chat/" + props.address_bar;

  return (
    <div>
      <NavLink to={addressBar}>
              .........jsx...........
      </NavLink>
    </div>
  );

Роутинг:
return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/chat" element={<Chat />} />
          </Routes>

    </BrowserRouter>
  );

Если не прокидывать props в url, то всё отлично работает. Если прокинуть, то html-разметка даже не создаётся при переходе на url + props.

я понял в чем дело. надо в path="/chat" добавить /:__ (в __ можно написать что угодно)))
<Route path="/chat/:id" element={<Chat />} />


Хочу добавить, что это называется URL Parameters
